# Install of MySQL on OSX runs on port 3307

Tags: mysql, macos, osx-yosemite

I just downloaded an installed MySQL on OSX 10.10.4 (Yosemite) from the latest DMG file.

looks like it's running on port 3307, not the standard 3306.
(e.g. telnet to localhost on 3306 times out, telnet to localhost on 3307 gives me the expected mysql propmpt)

After suffering with this, countless googling, trying to override it with a my.cnf file (port=3306), i have a workaround, just not sure it's sane.

In the System Preferences under MySQL, click the 'Automaticall Start MySQl Server on Startup' box.

This forces it to generate a launchDaemon in /Library/launchDaemons.

I then edited that file and changed the port to 3306 and restarted.

Works fine now.

But:

1. Why was it starting on 3307 to begin with? (one tech suggested Yosemite already had mysql installed and so it incremented the port number)
2. How will this bite me in the future?

Comment: I had this exact same problem, thank you for this! (I also believe this is the only way if you're using the preferences button)

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://superuser.com/questions/972276/mysql-binds-to-port-3307-not-port-3306) solution ?

Comment: I've always used the one packaged with [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) instead of the official installer. As far as I know it defaults to 3306. It's also a lot easier to upgrade, you can just `brew upgrade mysql` instead of having to download and run an installer program.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the mysql while trying to connect to localhost select socket flow.
For change this behavior you must change personal my.cnf
adding to a string

```
protocol=tcp
```

Example:
1) I see you problem:

$ mysql -h localhost -P 33306 -uyyyyyy -pzzzzz
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

2) I create ~/.my.cnf with:

```
[client]
protocol=tcp
```

and try:

```
$ mysql -h localhost -P 33306 -uyyyyyy -pzzzzz
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.

Your MySQL connection id is 566582
Server version: 5.5.44-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2015, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

everything is working